# Is it true that "there's no wrong in music"

Tags: performing

In the following question…

[Why do some of the chord choices in measures 18 through 20 of "Study #1 William Leavitt - Melodic Rhythms For Guitar" sound... "wrong"?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/130682/9426)

…a pupil says to their teacher that something sounds wrong. And the teacher responds by saying "there's no wrong in music".

Is the teacher correct?

Comment: You play me a nice chord sequence in C maj & i'll sing along with it in C♯. See how long you last ;) Also see Les Dawson - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9nNGlaiVypU also a much longer one at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQ0G2Z8k1Gg He was actually a consummate pianist, but he knew just exactly which would be the *worst* notes in any given situation.

Comment: @Tetsujin - It's actually not that easy to play proper Dawson style. I've tried many times. As far as C/C# goes, my party piece is r.h. key C, l.h. key C#, which isn't too easy. Great when trying out a used piano to buy...

Comment: It depends on your definition of "wrong" (and also on your definition of "music"). VTC as opinion-based

Comment: Note that even when people agree that there’s no “wrong” in music, there can absolutely be “wrong” in music *school*, so whatever you believe after you get an answer to this question, keep in mind that you can still get bad grades in a music class.

Comment: This question would be perfect for the chat room, since it's more a discussion topic than a question that can be answered factually.

Comment: I don't understand the basis of this question when it links to another post with answer explaining the performance in question _includes a performance mistake._ The "wrong" is playing the music not as notated, which isn't a matter right/wrong in the sense of aesthetics.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis Yes, this present question, besides dealing in vague terms with broad concepts, seems to deliberately misunderstand the misunderstanding. It seems the student suggested to the teacher that the composer had done something "wrong," when in fact the performer had incorrectly executed what was written. The abstruse argument about "no wrong in [music]" makes sense only when discussing creative output ("no wrong in [composing, improvising, etc.]"). Of course there is such a thing as errors in reading, and to induct them into an abstruse argument about aesthetics is sophistry.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and no. The teacher shouldn't respond with a glib "there's no wrong in music", if they're a good teacher. It may depend on the level of the student, but at any level, a far better answer should be forthcoming. "It *sounds* wrong because...", or "You could say it's wrong because..." would be the way I'd answer, at whatever appropriate level of musicality and understanding.

I would encourage students to ask 'demanding' and 'awkward' questions, which would either be answered directly (even though it may take us off track), or find an answer for next lesson. If they had the interest to ask the question, surely I, as teacher, should have the interest/experience to respond in a way that was palatable.

However, some students aren't ready for more of a stock answer than that - albeit few and far between. And some teachers just don't know, or care enough. Or can encapsulate the answer in a comprehensible way. So, far more incorrect than correct.

Answer (score 3):

It largely depends on the musical genre one is dealing with.

A sequence of melody notes may sound very 'off' in one genre but perfectly fine in another genre. The same applies to types of harmonies, chords, and chordal sequences. What may be typical in one genre (e.g. heavy rock) will probably sound very wrong in another genre (e.g. classical music).

Some genres, though, will lend themselves to fusing with others. So, you get hybrid genres whose individual genre rules *don't* clash and sound very wrong. (Country rock is an example.) Gospel or Blues will fuse and not sound wrong if mixed with the typical note/chord patterns of rock. But, I can't imagine Hip Hop sounding right blended with other genres, though you sometimes hear small sections of just hip hop spoken in parts of some pop songs.

What makes a piece of music *sound wrong* is if you break some of the essential rules that define its genre (eg the distinctive 12 bar, 8 bar etc blues chord sequence), or if you start to try and make very rhythmic hip hop with no melody, minimal instrumentation,  and heavy emphasis on clear, sharp diction to sound sweet and melodic. It just won't work.

But, oddly enough, some heavy rock/pop *can* sound OK given a classical interpretation/style. I have even heard some interesting heavy metal renditions of intensely profound religious music. Not surprising, since much metal genre music is preoccupied with death and spiritual stuff. Some classical music also sounded interesting, given a quietened down heavy metal treatment.

A person with an open mind might be able to appreciate this, but most classical musicians would be outraged and--surprise, surprise--if you asked some heavy metal bands to give you their rendition of a classical piece, they wouldn't have a bar of it. But the more creative, innovative ones might find it interesting to experiment, try something new, and see how it sounds.

I once watched such a metal band experimenting with various classical composers and, interestingly, the Germanic composers could be adapted to sound reasonable played as heavy metal/rock, or even deep wailing blues. But, the Latin composers (e.g. Italian) sounded very wrong given a metal treatment, though fine given a jazz or pop feeling. Spanish stuff sounded OK given a rock treatment, and some sad, wailing flamenco tunes sounded good given a blues interpretation.

It was great fun doing all this experimentation. I guess what's right or wrong depends on the genre and whether your ears like the sound waves produced or not.

Answer (score 2):

I play a fixed pitch instrument (concertina). I sometimes have the experience of playing with a violin player who has very dubious tuning, sometimes a quarter tone or more flat and increasingly flatter as they move further down the neck from (the already out-of-tune) open string.

That is wrong. There's no room for nonsense about temperament or 'violin tuning', just wrong. Rather like the teacher in the OP.